# Passport.js - Exchange authorization code received from the client for the access token

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

Google OAuth 2.0 recommends the [following](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) `oauth` flow:

> a hybrid server-side flow where a user authorizes your app on
>   the client side using the JavaScript API client and you send a special
>   one-time authorization code to your server. Your server exchanges this
>   one-time-use code to acquire its own access and refresh tokens from
>   Google for the server to be able to make its own API calls, which can
>   be done while the user is offline.

I am trying to do exactly this but using `passport.js` instead. In a normal (entirely server-side) workflow, Passport expects one-time authorization code from Google in a query parameter at the redirect link (for example: `/auth/google/redirect`). Hence, I would expect the same redirect endpoint to work if I call it from my client (with the authorization code), instead of Google redirecting it to.

However, when I try to do that, I get the following error from Passport:

```
TokenError: Bad Request
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:358:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:405:16)
    at node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:175:45
    at node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Is it incorrect to expect the code sent from my client-side to work this way? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into similar problems and have resolved them.

I have been trying to achive this behaviour with a React-Native app and a NodeJS server.

On the React-Native side, I am using the AuthSession module by Expo.
Following is the code:

```
let response = await AuthSession.startAsync({
    authUrl:
        `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?` +
        `&client_id=${GOOGLE_WEB_APP_ID}` +
        `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl)}` +
        `&response_type=code` +
        `&access_type=offline` +
        `&prompt=consent` +
        `&scope=profile`,
    // `&scope=${encodeURIComponent('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts')}`,
});
```

This returns a one-time use authorization code that can be exchanged with Google for a payload that looks like this:

```
    {
  "accessToken": "******",
  "idToken": "****",
  "refreshToken": "******",
  "type": "success",
  "user": Object {
    "email": "**********@gmail.com",
    "familyName": "P**********n",
    "givenName": "Aa******",
    "id": "1141489**************",
    "name": "******",
    "photoUrl": "**********",
  },
}
```

On the server-side, I was using the Google OAuth 2.0 Passport Strategy. https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-oauth20

The problem though, is that this strategy is not particularly useful in my case since it does not use the one-time use Authorization Code.

As a replacement, I was checking out https://github.com/shobhitsinghal624/passport-google-authcode

Currently, I am in the process of writing a similar module for my own use as it seems like a pretty niche requirement.